# Android : Parse using xmlpullparser

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I have a xml file in the location `res/xml/data.xml`
I need to parse that xml file

`XmlResourceParser xrp=context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.data);`

I used this code to get that file. It returns as `XmlResourceParser`
Also tried with `xmlpullparser`

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
```

I am not getting clear idea between these two parser. My question is how to parse a xml file in the resource folder using `xmlpullparser`?

Answer (score 2):

`XmlResourceParser`  is an `interface` which extends `XmlPullParser`.

`getXml` wil return the `XmlResourceParser` object. You can read the parser text similar to how we parse the input stream or a string using `XMLPullParser`

Here is a sample code to parse from resource xml

```
 try {
        XmlResourceParser xmlResourceParser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.data);

        int eventType = xmlResourceParser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                System.out.println("Start document");
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                System.out.println("Start tag " + xmlResourceParser.getName());
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                System.out.println("End tag " + xmlResourceParser.getName());
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                System.out.println("Text " + xmlResourceParser.getText());
            }
            eventType = xmlResourceParser.next();
        }
        System.out.println("End document");
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: how to get data inside <a>xxx</a> using tag name

Comment: xmlResourceParser.getText() will return the data when eventType is TEXT