# myParser.getText always return null

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

so, i'm pretty noob and I'm trying to parse [this xml](http://tvprofil.net/xmltv/data/rai-1.it/weekly_rai-1.it_tvprofil.net.xml) to get a list of italian tv programmes.
But when i use myParser.getText it will return null.
I actually get into the node but then it wont get any value from it.

```
    public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
    int event;
    String text=null;
    try {
        event = myParser.getEventType();
        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String name=myParser.getName();
            switch (event){

                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if(name.equals("display-name")){
                        channel = myParser.getText();
                        Log.d(name+" -->",myParser.getText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equals("programme")){
                        hour = myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"start");
                        Log.d(name+" -->",hour);
                    }
                    else if(name.equals("title")){
                        programme = myParser.getText();
                        Log.d(name+" -->",myParser.getText());
                    }
                    else if(name.equals("desc")){
                        description =  myParser.getText();
                        Log.d(name+" -->",myParser.getText());
                    }
                    else {}
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            }
            event = myParser.next();
        }
        parsingComplete = false;
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now my log wont return anything cause myParser.getText is null, but if i print just the name it actually will return me the node.
getAttributeValue works, but i need it in just this case

```
else if(name.equals("programme")){
                        hour = myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"start");
                        Log.d(name+" -->",hour);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XmlResourceParser.getText() returning null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685464/xmlresourceparser-gettext-returning-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I am late but I would like to introduce [simple framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php) for xml parsing.

to add this library by adding this line to the build.gradle of app module

```
compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.5'
```

Given below is the code that may help you parse the xml

**Code**

```
public class TestDriveTv {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        String path = "http://tvprofil.net/xmltv/data/rai-1.it/weekly_rai-1.it_tvprofil.net.xml";
        URL url = new URL(path);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.connect();


        Serializer serializer = new Persister();

        Tv tv = serializer.read(Tv.class, httpURLConnection.getInputStream());

        printText(tv.getSource_data_url());
        printText(tv.getSource_info_name());
        printText(tv.getSource_info_url());
        printText("\n");

        for (Programme programme:tv.getProgrammes()){

            printText("##Program##");

            printText(programme.getChannel());
            printText(programme.getStart());
            printText(programme.getStop());
            printText(programme.getTitle());
            printText(programme.getCategory());
            printText(programme.getDesc());

            printText("\n");
        }

    }

    public static String getPath() {
        return Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString();
    }

    public static void printText(String text) {
        System.out.println("" + text);
    }
}
```

**TV**

```
@Root(name = "tv", strict = false)
public class Tv {

    @Attribute(name = "source-data-url", required = false)
    private String source_data_url;

    @Attribute(name = "source-info-name", required = false)
    private String source_info_name;

    @Attribute(name = "source-info-url", required = false)
    private String source_info_url;

    @ElementList(name = "programme",inline = true, required = false)
    private List<Programme> programmes;

    public String getSource_data_url() {
        return source_data_url;
    }

    public void setSource_data_url(String source_data_url) {
        this.source_data_url = source_data_url;
    }

    public String getSource_info_name() {
        return source_info_name;
    }

    public void setSource_info_name(String source_info_name) {
        this.source_info_name = source_info_name;
    }

    public String getSource_info_url() {
        return source_info_url;
    }

    public void setSource_info_url(String source_info_url) {
        this.source_info_url = source_info_url;
    }

    public List<Programme> getProgrammes() {
        return programmes;
    }

    public void setProgrammes(List<Programme> programmes) {
        this.programmes = programmes;
    }
}
```

**Channel**

```
@Root(name = "channel", strict = false)
public class Channel {

    @Attribute(name = "id", required = false)
    private String id;

    @Element(name = "display-name", required = false)
    private String display_name;

    @Element(name = "url", required = false)
    private String url;

    @Element(name = "icon", required = false)
    private String icon;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDisplay_name() {
        return display_name;
    }

    public void setDisplay_name(String display_name) {
        this.display_name = display_name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

**Programme**

```
@Root(name = "programme", strict = false)
public class Programme {

    @Attribute(name = "channel", required = false)
    private String channel;

    @Attribute(name = "start", required = false)
    private String start;

    @Attribute(name = "stop", required = false)
    private String stop;

    @Element(name = "title", required = false)
    private String title;

    @Element(name = "category", required = false)
    private String category;

    @Element(name = "desc", required = false)
    private String desc;

    public String getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(String channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public String getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(String start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public String getStop() {
        return stop;
    }

    public void setStop(String stop) {
        this.stop = stop;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
http://tvprofil.net/xmltv/
Phazer XML servis 4.6
http://tvprofil.net


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607060000 +0200
20160607063000 +0200
Il caffè di Raiuno
null
null


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607063000 +0200
20160607064300 +0200
TG 1
vijesti
Segui gli appuntamenti quotidiani del Tg1, rivedi on line l'ultima edizione. Entra nel sito e scopri tutte le rubriche.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607064300 +0200
20160607064500 +0200
CCISS Viaggiare informati
vijesti
Lo spazio dedicato a chi si mette in viaggio. Informazioni su viabilità, condizioni meteorologiche, interruzioni stradali e percorsi alternativi con aggiornamenti in tempo reale.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607064500 +0200
20160607064900 +0200
Unomattina Estate
vijesti
Spazio alla cronaca, all'attualità, alla politica, al costume e al sociale con collegamenti con le sedi regionale e estere. In collaborazione con il Tg1, la conduzione è stata affidata a Mia Ceran e Alessio Zucchini, mentre la postazione web, dedicata alle agenzie e ai giornali esteri, sarà occupata da Antonia Varini.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607064900 +0200
20160607065000 +0200
Che tempo fa, informazione
vijesti
null


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607065000 +0200
20160607065500 +0200
Unomattina Estate
vijesti
Spazio alla cronaca, all'attualità, alla politica, al costume e al sociale con collegamenti con le sedi regionale e estere. In collaborazione con il Tg1, la conduzione è stata affidata a Mia Ceran e Alessio Zucchini, mentre la postazione web, dedicata alle agenzie e ai giornali esteri, sarà occupata da Antonia Varini.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607065500 +0200
20160607070000 +0200
Parlamento Telegiornale
vijesti
Un breve panorama quotidiano sulle sedute di Camera e Senato. Un'agenda sull'attività parlamentare del giorno.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607070000 +0200
20160607071000 +0200
TG 1
vijesti
Segui gli appuntamenti quotidiani del Tg1, rivedi on line l'ultima edizione. Entra nel sito e scopri tutte le rubriche.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607071000 +0200
20160607073000 +0200
Unomattina Estate
vijesti
Spazio alla cronaca, all'attualità, alla politica, al costume e al sociale con collegamenti con le sedi regionale e estere. In collaborazione con il Tg1, la conduzione è stata affidata a Mia Ceran e Alessio Zucchini, mentre la postazione web, dedicata alle agenzie e ai giornali esteri, sarà occupata da Antonia Varini.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607073000 +0200
20160607073300 +0200
TG 1 L.I.S.
vijesti
Segui gli appuntamenti quotidiani del Tg1, rivedi on line l'ultima edizione. Entra nel sito e scopri tutte le rubriche.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607073300 +0200
20160607075300 +0200
Unomattina Estate
vijesti
Spazio alla cronaca, all'attualità, alla politica, al costume e al sociale con collegamenti con le sedi regionale e estere. In collaborazione con il Tg1, la conduzione è stata affidata a Mia Ceran e Alessio Zucchini, mentre la postazione web, dedicata alle agenzie e ai giornali esteri, sarà occupata da Antonia Varini.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607075300 +0200
20160607075500 +0200
Che tempo fa, informazione
vijesti
null


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607075500 +0200
20160607080000 +0200
Unomattina Estate
vijesti
Spazio alla cronaca, all'attualità, alla politica, al costume e al sociale con collegamenti con le sedi regionale e estere. In collaborazione con il Tg1, la conduzione è stata affidata a Mia Ceran e Alessio Zucchini, mentre la postazione web, dedicata alle agenzie e ai giornali esteri, sarà occupata da Antonia Varini.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607080000 +0200
20160607082500 +0200
TG 1
vijesti
Segui gli appuntamenti quotidiani del Tg1, rivedi on line l'ultima edizione. Entra nel sito e scopri tutte le rubriche.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607082500 +0200
20160607082700 +0200
Che tempo fa, informazione
vijesti
null


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607082700 +0200
20160607090000 +0200
Unomattina Estate
vijesti
Spazio alla cronaca, all'attualità, alla politica, al costume e al sociale con collegamenti con le sedi regionale e estere. In collaborazione con il Tg1, la conduzione è stata affidata a Mia Ceran e Alessio Zucchini, mentre la postazione web, dedicata alle agenzie e ai giornali esteri, sarà occupata da Antonia Varini.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607090000 +0200
20160607090300 +0200
TG 1
vijesti
Segui gli appuntamenti quotidiani del Tg1, rivedi on line l'ultima edizione. Entra nel sito e scopri tutte le rubriche.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607090300 +0200
20160607090500 +0200
Che tempo fa, informazione
vijesti
null


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607090500 +0200
20160607093000 +0200
Unomattina Estate
vijesti
Spazio alla cronaca, all'attualità, alla politica, al costume e al sociale con collegamenti con le sedi regionale e estere. In collaborazione con il Tg1, la conduzione è stata affidata a Mia Ceran e Alessio Zucchini, mentre la postazione web, dedicata alle agenzie e ai giornali esteri, sarà occupata da Antonia Varini.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607093000 +0200
20160607093500 +0200
TG1 FLASH
vijesti
Segui gli appuntamenti quotidiani del Tg1, rivedi on line l'ultima edizione. Entra nel sito e scopri tutte le rubriche.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607093500 +0200
20160607100000 +0200
Unomattina Estate
vijesti
Spazio alla cronaca, all'attualità, alla politica, al costume e al sociale con collegamenti con le sedi regionale e estere. In collaborazione con il Tg1, la conduzione è stata affidata a Mia Ceran e Alessio Zucchini, mentre la postazione web, dedicata alle agenzie e ai giornali esteri, sarà occupata da Antonia Varini.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607100000 +0200
20160607100500 +0200
TG 1
vijesti
Segui gli appuntamenti quotidiani del Tg1, rivedi on line l'ultima edizione. Entra nel sito e scopri tutte le rubriche.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607100500 +0200
20160607104500 +0200
Unomattina Estate
vijesti
Spazio alla cronaca, all'attualità, alla politica, al costume e al sociale con collegamenti con le sedi regionale e estere. In collaborazione con il Tg1, la conduzione è stata affidata a Mia Ceran e Alessio Zucchini, mentre la postazione web, dedicata alle agenzie e ai giornali esteri, sarà occupata da Antonia Varini.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607104500 +0200
20160607113000 +0200
Reef Doctors - dottori a Hope Island, serie, Oltre la paura
serija
TELEFILM Reef Doctors - dottori a Hope Island - Oltre la paura 1^ Visione RAI.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607113000 +0200
20160607133000 +0200
Don Matteo 6 - st 06
serija
La Rai Radiotelevisione Italiana presenta Don Matteo 6 - Francesca e il lupo - La giostra dei desideri.
Lo chiamano il detective al servizio di Dio: è il prete investigatore, astuto e simpatico che concilia la tradizionale missione pastorale con la passione per l'investigazione. È Don Matteo Bondini.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607133000 +0200
20160607140000 +0200
TELEGIORNALE
vijesti
Segui gli appuntamenti quotidiani del Tg1, rivedi on line l'ultima edizione. Entra nel sito e scopri tutte le rubriche.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607140000 +0200
20160607140500 +0200
TG1 Economia
vijesti
Quotidiano di informazione sull'Azienda Italia A cura della Redazione Economico Sindacale.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607140500 +0200
20160607153500 +0200
Estate in diretta
show
Dalle ore 14.05 alle ore 15.50 Conduce: Arianna Ciampoli Dalle ore 16.40 alle ore 18.40 Conducono: Eleonora Daniele e Salvo Sottile Estate in diretta è un programma di attualità, cronaca e spettacolo. Sarà una grande finestra su tutti gli avvenimenti dellestate raccontati in studio e approfonditi da collegamenti in diretta e da servizi fumati. Un grande racconto popolare che vuole coinvolgere e appassionare il pubblico a casa sui grandi temi di interesse generale. La prima parte del programma s... (more at http://tvprofil.net)


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607153500 +0200
20160607162700 +0200
SOAP Legami
null
null


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607162700 +0200
20160607163000 +0200
Che tempo fa, informazione
vijesti
null


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607163000 +0200
20160607164000 +0200
TG 1
vijesti
Segui gli appuntamenti quotidiani del Tg1, rivedi on line l'ultima edizione. Entra nel sito e scopri tutte le rubriche.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607164000 +0200
20160607184500 +0200
Estate in diretta
show
Dalle ore 14.05 alle ore 15.50 Conduce: Arianna Ciampoli Dalle ore 16.40 alle ore 18.40 Conducono: Eleonora Daniele e Salvo Sottile Estate in diretta è un programma di attualità, cronaca e spettacolo. Sarà una grande finestra su tutti gli avvenimenti dellestate raccontati in studio e approfonditi da collegamenti in diretta e da servizi fumati. Un grande racconto popolare che vuole coinvolgere e appassionare il pubblico a casa sui grandi temi di interesse generale. La prima parte del programma s... (more at http://tvprofil.net)


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607184500 +0200
20160607200000 +0200
Reazione a Catena, quiz
show
null


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607200000 +0200
20160607203000 +0200
TELEGIORNALE
vijesti
Segui gli appuntamenti quotidiani del Tg1, rivedi on line l'ultima edizione. Entra nel sito e scopri tutte le rubriche.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607203000 +0200
20160607233000 +0200
Wind Music Awards 2016, musica
null
null


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607233000 +0200
20160607233300 +0200
TG1 60 Secondi
vijesti
Segui gli appuntamenti quotidiani del Tg1, rivedi on line l'ultima edizione. Entra nel sito e scopri tutte le rubriche.


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160607233300 +0200
20160608000000 +0200
Wind Music Awards 2016, musica
null
null


##Program##
rai-1.it
20160608000000 +0200
20160608012000 +0200
Porta a Porta
vijesti
La seconda serata di Rai Uno nel salotto di Bruno Vespa: con i suoi ospiti approfondisce i temi di attualità, cronaca e politica.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the variables you declared `channel, hour, programme, description` are class variables? I don't see where these are declared, but want to make sure.

As for `getText()` I think you need to actually use this in the `TEXT` event, not the `START_TAG`

> > getText
>
> Added in API level 1 String getText ()
>
> Returns the text content of the current event as String. The value
>   returned depends on current event type, for example for TEXT event it
>   is element content (this is typical case when next() is used). See
>   description of nextToken() for detailed description of possible
>   returned values for different types of events.

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getText()